# Auto format pivot table drill down

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in excel that shows referral domains to our website. When you drill down it shows the specific pages that the referrals came from. The pivot table is sorted by the number of referrals (highest to lowest). However, when you drill down there is no order whatsoever. While, sorting the drill down manually isn't that difficult, I'm using the spreadsheet in a presentation and don't want to have to play with the data and formatting while I'm presenting.

Is there a way to auto-format the drill down? Like sort by number of referrals and maybe resize a few rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in the Thisworkbook code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
ans = MsgBox("Format this sheet?", vbYesNo)
If ans = vbYes Then doFormatting Sh
End Sub
```

and this in a standard code module:

```
Sub doFormatting(sht As Worksheet)
MsgBox "formatting new sheet: " & sht.Name
End Sub
```

*(of course, insert your formatting as desired)*

Comment: Sean, this seems to work great, I got the resizing to work. I do have another question. I'm fairly new to VBA, where could I find some information on the code to sort? I don't even know where to start to get that to work.

Comment: record macro is an ideal place to see what code is required. there's many times I've recorded a macro, then edited that macro to be more general for my use (and press `F1` in the code to understand the parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your looking for a vba solution but I'm pretty sure that functionality is already there.

You can sort any drill down field.

If clicking a couple buttons is too much to worry about during the presentation then I would recommend just putting a modified copy of the pivot table on the next powerpoint slide/sheet.

For example:

[image: Pivot Table Explanation]

I'm not sure if this image is showing up for you.